# Concatenate httpresponse objects django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am developing a website with django and want to keep a common template for header and footer. The contents of the header and footer vary with respect to the user logged in. So is there a way where i could use:

```
    header=render_to_response('header.html',{....})
    footer=render_to_response('footer.html',{....})
    content=render_to_response('content.html',{....})
    return header+content+footer
```

Comment: render_to_string does this... just found out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Harsh, concatenating `HttpResponse` objects is not the way to do it. Django's (and I believe, reasonable) approach recommends using templates including and inheritance. Please, take a look at `{% block %}`, `{% include %}` and `{% extend %}` template tags [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

In your case the way to implement template inheritance looks like:

*base.html* :

```
<div> header code </div>
{% block content %}
    <div>Default content</div>
{% endblock content %}
<div> footer code </div>
```

*my.template.html* :

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div>My new content</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance).

Basically, this allows you to have a "Base" template with  your header and footer, where you define (for instance) a "Content Block".

You then have your other templates "extend" the Base template by filling in the (empty or not) blocks you defined in your Base template.

Using render_to_string as you're doing is not the proper way of doing this in Django.